# Unique values based on multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns which contains duplicate entries. See example below. 
I want to remove duplicates from both columns
Original Column

```
MatchN  Striker
1000887 DA Warner
1000887 DA Warner
1000887 TM Head
1000887 TM Head
```

I would like to finally get the result as

```
MatchN  Striker
1000887 DA Warner
1000887 TM Head
```

I tried using

```
np.df[["MatchN"],["Striker"]].unique()
```

but it does not work.

Can anyone please suggest best way to get to the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method:

```
In [69]: df = df.drop_duplicates(['MatchN','Striker'])

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
    MatchN    Striker
0  1000887  DA Warner
2  1000887    TM Head
```

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(["MatchN"],["Striker"]) does not work

Comment: @AnoopMahajan, you should have posted a reproducible data set... Pleaase check updated answer

Comment: @AnoopMahajan, glad i could help :)